# Dropdown component not show selected option Laravel inertia (vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

hi all I'm using laravel inertia and I'm filling a Dropdown with locations. But when I select one, doesn't show as a selected item in the dropdown. I need help to load the selected option.
When I select one. in console I get "Cannot create property 'id' on string ''

Here I describe my code

#### **Function create in CompanyController**

```
`public function create()     {         $locations = Location::orderBy('name')->get();         return Inertia::render('Companies/Create', [             'locations' => $locations,         ]);     }`
```

if I inspect on vuedevtools, I can see the locations array

In my Dropdown I've done a foreach locations in #content section.

#### Dropdown component

```
<Dropdown align="left" width="60">
    <template #trigger>
        <div class="relative">
            <button type="button"
                    class="inline-flex justify-between w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                    id="options-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <span v-if="form.locations === ''">Select Location</span>
                <span v-else>{{ form.locations }}</span>
                <svg class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                     fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M5 8a1 1 0 011.707 0L10 11.293l3.293-3.294a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4A1 1 0 015 8z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <template #content>
        <div class="py-1" role="none">

            <button v-for="location in locations" :key="location.id" type="button"
                    class="block w-full text-left px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900"
                    role="menuitem" @click="form.locations.id = location.id">
                {{ location.name }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </template>
</Dropdown>
```

```

#### Here some screenshots of the form view (locations are faker words)
[image]

#### screenshot of error in console (when location is selected)
[image]

Here the complete Create Component
https://codeshare.io/N3Mxw1

Thanks in advance

I spect all locations filled on Dorpdown component and whe a location is selected, its show in dropdown, ready to send to store by id.

Comment: its because the `form.location` is a string you cannot add a property since `property` is for an Object.

Comment: Can you explain more. do you want to add one or more selected items ?

Comment: Hi @xenooooo
no. I only need to take the selected item and show it in the Dropdown.

Comment: Can you try `form.location = location.id`